# Is it allowed to cast a char[] to unsigned char *?

Tags: c++

I was using some class which has a method requiring:

```
const unsigned char *sData
```

as parameter.

When I called following:

```
char dataIn[]="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";     
obj.CRC(dataIn,strlen(dataIn),&checksum); // compute checksum
```

I got error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void crcClass::CRC(const unsigned char *,size_t,unsigned int *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [44]' to 'const unsigned char *'
```

So I modified above code like this and it works:

```
obj.CRC((const unsigned char*)dataIn,strlen(dataIn),&checksum); // compute checksum
```

Is the modification I did alright?

Comment: You called a completely different method; what does the documentation say?

Comment: No no it is same method I made error while typing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's OK, but for "safety" consider using `reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(dataIn)` instead.

This is safer in the sense that the `reinterpret_cast` cannot remove `const` or `volatile`, whereas the C-style cast can. If you don't want to remove qualifiers then it's nice for the code to fail to compile when you get it wrong.

Of course, in this case there's little chance of getting it wrong -- the destination is `const`-qualified and you'd probably notice if the source was `volatile`-qualified. But it's still useful to get into the habit of letting the compiler help you, plus some people will consider the code easier to read.

Comment: The C++-style cast is definitely easier to read. Or well, ... at least it looks better.

Comment: @H2CO3: yep, you'd be one of these people then ;-)

Comment: Exactly, I love C but one of its fundamental flaws is that casts are ugly :P

Comment: Another option in C++ is `typedef const unsigned char *byteptr`, then use `byteptr(dataIn)`. Sometimes readers don't realise that has the same semantics as the C-style cast, and think 1-arg constructor calls are somehow more virtuous than C-style casts.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `static_cast`. I find functional-style casts quite confusing.

Comment: In this case wouldn't that be even better to just `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(dataIn)` and just let the const be applied implicitly ?

Comment: @Drax: depends whether you want to have to change this line of code in the case that you later change `dataIn` to a `const char` array. Casting to a `const` type makes the minimum possible requirements on the source of the cast. I don't think it's necessarily a clear win either way.

Comment: ok so far I might go with the version I had (using normal cast), if it doesn't do much damage.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, add an overload for plain `char`, and hide the cast inside of the CRC class:

```
class crc32 {

    // ...
    unsigned int CRC(unsigned char const *in) { 
       // existing function
    }

    unsigned int CRC(char const *in) { 
       // pass through to preceding function:
       return CRC(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(in);
    }
};
```

I'd also note that at first glance `crc32::CRC` looks suspect to me. It looks like it may make more sense for this to be written as an overload of `operator()` instead.